# Expect script: remove password on private key

Tags: scripting, expect

I'm trying to remove the password on a private key. Doing it by hand is simple, I run this command and enter the password : `openssl rsa <newkey.pem > newkey-no-password.pem`

I'm trying to do this in an expect script, so that I don't have to actually type the password. Here is the code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set PASSWORD myPassword

spawn openssl rsa <newkey.pem > newkey-no-pass.pem
expect "Enter pass phrase:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect eof
```

And here is the output I get when running the script:

```
[me@mymachine]# ./test.exp
spawn openssl rsa <newkey.pem > newkey-no-pass.pem
unknown option <newkey.pem
rsa [options] <infile >outfile
... all the options for rsa command ...
```

I tried putting the `<newkey.pem` between `'` or `"`, to no avail.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `spawn` command does not parse shell redirections `<`. You can make it work by passing it through a shell with `sh -c`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set PASSWORD myPassword

spawn sh -c "openssl rsa <newkey.pem > newkey-no-pass.pem"
expect "Enter pass phrase:"
send "$PASSWORD\r"
expect eof
```

It works for me:

```
# expect -f kkf
spawn sh -c openssl rsa <newkey.pem > newkey-no-pass.pem
Enter pass phrase:myPassword
writing RSA key
```

Comment: Alternatively you can give `openssl rsa` options `-in file` and `-out file` instead of using redirections. For that matter, you can just give option `-passin pass:mypasswd` and it won't prompt at all; however, this will usually be visible, very briefly, to anyone who runs `ps` or reads `/proc/n/cmdline` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to extract private key and remove password from a pkcs12 file :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in myFile.p12 -nocerts -out myFile.priv.password.pem -passin pass:SomePassword -passout pass:SomeOtherPassword

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -inform pem -in myFile.priv.password.pem -passin pass:SomeOtherPassword -outform pem -out myFile.priv.pem
```

Some my guess is : this should work for you :

```
openssl rsa -in newkey.pem -out newkey-no-pass.pem -passin pass:SomePassword
```

If you don't want the password on the command line, you can use a file (with restricted access) :

```
openssl rsa -in newkey.pem -out newkey-no-pass.pem -passin file:PasswordFile.txt
```